# Understanding the mathematics in the following article about EMC

Tags: pcb-design, emc

I am currently studying the following reference about EMC, and try to understand the mathematics done in chapter 2 "What do we mean by high speed". The link to the reference is given below:

https://www.cherryclough.com/media/file/EMC%20for%20PCB/Parts%200%20and%201.pdf

In chapter 2, the author writes:

> The velocity of electromagnetic propagation is limited by the laws of nature, and in an FR4 PCB it is
> approximately 50% of the free-space velocity of \$3*10^8 m/s\$, say 6.67ns per metre (2ns per foot). So
> we can associate an ‘edge length’ in millimetres or inches with each rising or falling edge of a signal.
> So a 1ns edge has an ’edge length’ in an FR4 PCB of approximately 75mm (3 inches).

Electromagnetic propagation in air is \$3*10^8 m/s\$, and on FR4 PCB, it is 50% of that. So:
\$0.5*3*10^8 m/s = 1.5*10^8 m/s\$
The inverse of that gives \$1/(1.5*10^8 m/s) = 6.67 ns / m\$.

That I understand. If we assume a 1ns (rising) edge on a signal, why do we have an edge length of approx. 75mm? Shouldn't it be \$1ns/(6.67 ns/m) = 0.150m = 150mm\$? Why does he have half of my calculation?

Also, going a step further, the author claims

> The rule of thumb is that we usually need to design the PCB using transmission-line techniques
> when the edge length is shorter than three times the longest dimension of a PCB. So for a PCB that
> has a longest dimension of 150mm (6 inches) we would categorise edge rates of 3ns and less as
> “high-speed”

Previously, we had 1ns edge having an edge length of 75mm. Now we are saying that a 3ns edge should be treated as a transmission line if the track length is min. 150mm. Also, the author seems to mix "edge [ns]" with "edge length [mm]".

Anyone here who can help me demystify the math, or is there really something odd in the text?

Thank you,

Comment: Sometimes in a transmission line you are interested in the round trip of a signal (pulse or edge); i.e. down the line, bounce off an impedance mismatch at the far end, and back to the sender. That means the signal travels 150mm on a 75mm trace. Does that make sense in this context?

Comment: @Brian you’re correct, but perhaps being rather generous to the author, as this doesn’t appear to be spelled out; if it is intentional then it’s understandably confusing to the reader.  It’s also worth gearing in mind that there’s nothing magic about three times the longest dimension- as speed increases the transmission line effects become progressively more important.

Comment: @Frog I was assuming it was spelled out somewhere other than the quoted passages, and might appear on re-reading with a view to finding it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - It does not entirely make sense to me. Am I correct in my understanding that the "edge length" translates the distance the signal has traveled given its speed (6.67ns/m on FR4 PCB) during the "rising time of the edge"? If the rising time is 1ns, it means that it takes 1ns for the signal to go from 10% to 90% (or 0% to 100% if you want). The edge length means, how much distance has the signal traveled on the PCB during this 1ns. I do not see how impedance mismatch or round trips come into play in this context. There's probably something I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

This text only refers to rise time (edge or step) relative to propagation delay. He is saying the Rule of Thumb is the max length should be < 3x the propagation delay (1way) but if < 6x the prop delay it would be called "high-speed" and impedance matching becomes important.

This rule of thumb has repercussions in other areas of EMC, namely;

1. unintended RF radiation or conduction = **egress**
2. undesirable RF susceptibility by conduction or radiation = **ingress**
3. spectral impedance: mismatch or matching or transformation
4. Return Loss (RL) with spectral amplification or attenuation,
5. Propagation delay, echo amplitude (RL) from mismatch, overshoot, ringing
6. **Rise time relative to propagation delay**, with mismatched loads relative to signal path Zo
7. Signal integrity for logic and noise margin.
8. Physical track width, W and gap, G to ground track(s) or ground plane(s) with W/G from 2 to <<0.1

   - this results in impedance Zo for signals with wavelengths < 10x the path length with \$Z_o=\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$
   - affects L from 0.5 to >1nH/mm from wide to long thin tracks
   - and (est.?) C=0.1pF to 1pF/mm for no ground plane to with a ground plane and very thin dielectric

Finally we can correlate f-3dB to the edge or risetime from 10 to 90% using.

- \$f_{-3dB}=\dfrac{0.35}{t_R}=\dfrac{0.35}{>3 length} ~ \$

### Conclusion

- i.e. the signal path  circuit path of more than 10% of the standing wavelength of the max frequency component then controlled impedance must be used.  It essentially limits the path length of an uncontrolled impedance transmission line not the max length of a matched impedance line...

  - ~~ This the Rule I used. ~~

For a [simulation of what happens when you violate this rule](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCDMB0CsCmBaAjAJhKmAWA7GWAnKsgGwk6xiSwhaQjIRaoBQASgyRlhIlgBzcmIGqjD8wkySPCyw0ZCwBOnDDnQC16CJRYB5LYdTqhclshzIGOLha7H0d2ciQEMkeTVLgWAc2u2RAEY4mb%20DgxBEWKCEGAsADYYqFhGJhEQ-EiCiPKSWAQEFLgkqPw2sLCKAMZp6NH8sRhIaLRwjGIEuNSN6m55YIoq3k6aTjrxAO6qKRAjNj7TYwtO435GjYaQYmYGEU77WKlxLNPeszMmU7SC0SmG8QD2siTHImjoXHmoNBDaUCxnq1Xs5IJBkKl%20NBiDh%20JB%20FhXpACKR6ANBgwGICMCAQXMwRCQFDICRYKTYVQSARqF9oFIrI4WPCoJjKAwpCAAJIAWwADvAACYAQwAdtV4AAdADOlAAfsgANZMpr0RhSDlq9XSABiSngAEcAK7wMUATxYQA)

[image]

In regards to your question 75mm/ns vs 150 mm/ns is just another way to defining "High Speed" for both ends mismatched and 2 way echo time.  This means for all 3.6V logic with < 1ns rise time you ought to be using controlled impedance and also possibly for 5.5V logic family in PCB layout.  Whereas in old CMOS 4xxx family we did not have to.

Comment: Who's the troll -1?

Comment: I will have to digest your input and probably also read some more literature on this topic to better educate myself. Because right now, we're already going deep down into transmission line theory and impedance mismatching, whereas the quote from me solely talks about rise time in [ns], velocity in [mm/ns] and "edge length" in [mm]. Waves traveling back and forth and impedance mismatching has nowhere been mentioned or introduced in the text. So I probably need to do some background reading myself, or find a proper source to read.

Comment: When you know it’s rise time relative and Path wavelength is HF then it must be controlled impedance in TL theory which Also implies EMC. But its similar to a distributed RLC filter as I showed for 1ns example, which applies to 74ALC etc

Comment: The simple answer is 1/10 of a wavelength or more is equivalent. 1/20th for mismatched at both ends

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 fixed your -1 :)